# what's the difference between torch.Tensor() vs torch.empty() in pytorch?

Tags: python, pytorch, torch, tensor

I have tried it out as below. It seems to me they're the same. What's the difference between torch.Tensor() vs torch.empty() in pytorch?

[image]

Answer (score 18, accepted):

[`torch.Tensor()` is just an alias to `torch.FloatTensor()`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/tensors.html#torch-tensor) which is the default type of tensor, when no `dtype` is specified during tensor construction.

From the [torch for numpy users notes](https://github.com/torch/torch7/wiki/Torch-for-Numpy-users#ones-and-zeros), it seems that `torch.Tensor()` is a drop-in replacement of `numpy.empty()`

So, in essence `torch.FloatTensor()` and `torch.empty()` does the same job of returning a tensor filled with garbage values of dtype `torch.float32`. Below is a small run:

```
In [87]: torch.FloatTensor(2, 3)
Out[87]: 
tensor([[-1.0049e+08,  4.5688e-41, -8.9389e-38],
        [ 3.0638e-41,  4.4842e-44,  0.0000e+00]])

In [88]: torch.FloatTensor(2, 3)
Out[88]: 
tensor([[-1.0049e+08,  4.5688e-41, -1.6512e-38],
        [ 3.0638e-41,  4.4842e-44,  0.0000e+00]])
```

---

```
In [89]: torch.empty(2, 3)
Out[89]: 
tensor([[-1.0049e+08,  4.5688e-41, -9.0400e-38],
        [ 3.0638e-41,  4.4842e-44,  0.0000e+00]])

In [90]: torch.empty(2, 3)
Out[90]: 
tensor([[-1.0049e+08,  4.5688e-41, -9.2852e-38],
        [ 3.0638e-41,  4.4842e-44,  0.0000e+00]])
```

Comment: i was trying to create a tensor with tensor.Tensor and getting errors. Please take a look at the following post. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51160386/unable-to-create-a-tensor-using-torch-tensor

Comment: Worth to mention misleading tutor https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/blitz/tensor_tutorial.html that prints zeros for `torch.empty` which is not true.

Answer (score 5):

***Quick Answer:*** 
torch.empty() creates tensor with any data type you want, torch.Tensor() only creates tensors of type torch.FloatTensor. 
So torch.Tensor() is a special case of torch.empty()

***Detailed Answer:***

torch.empty() returns a tensor filled with uninitialized data. With arguments you can specify the shape of the tensor, the output tensor, the data type... [(see tensor.empty() documentation )](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/torch.html)

This means you can create a tensor of floats, int... If no data type is specified then the chosen one is your default **torch.Tensor** type (which is torch.FloatTensor by default and you can change it using [torch.set_default_tensor_type()](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/torch.html#torch.set_default_tensor_type))

torch.Tensor() is simply a special case of torch.empty() where the data type is torch.FloatTensor.