# Unable to create a tensor using torch.Tensor

Tags: python, runtime-error, pytorch, tensor

i was trying to create a tensor as below.

```
import torch
t = torch.tensor(2,3)
```

i got the following error.

> TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call
>   last)  in ()
>   ----> 1 a=torch.tensor(2,3)
>
> TypeError: tensor() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

so, i tried the following

```
import torch
t = torch.Tensor(2,3)
# No error while creating the tensor
# When i print i get an error
print(t)
```

i get the following error

> RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call
>   last)  in ()
>   ----> 1 print(a)
>
> D:\softwares\anaconda\lib\site-packages\torch\tensor.py in
>   **repr**(self)
>        55         # characters to replace unicode characters with.
>        56         if sys.version_info > (3,):
>   ---> 57             return torch._tensor_str._str(self)
>        58         else:
>        59             if hasattr(sys.stdout, 'encoding'):
>
> D:\softwares\anaconda\lib\site-packages\torch_tensor_str.py in
>   _str(self)
>       216             suffix = ', dtype=' + str(self.dtype) + suffix
>       217
>   --> 218         fmt, scale, sz = _number_format(self)
>       219         if scale != 1:
>       220             prefix = prefix + SCALE_FORMAT.format(scale) + ' ' * indent
>
> D:\softwares\anaconda\lib\site-packages\torch_tensor_str.py in
>   _number_format(tensor, min_sz)
>        94     # TODO: use fmod?
>        95     for value in tensor:
>   ---> 96         if value != math.ceil(value.item()):
>        97             int_mode = False
>        98             break
>
> RuntimeError: Overflow when unpacking long

But, according to [This SO Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51129043/whats-the-difference-between-torch-tensor-vs-torch-empty-in-pytorch), he was able to create a tensor. Am i missing something here. Also, why was i able to create a tensor with `Tensor`(capital T) and not with `tensor`(small t)

[image: Please look at the error.]

Comment: https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/torch.html#torch.tensor suggests that tensor's first argument is `data` and its second is `dtype`. I don't think it makes much sense to do `t = torch.tensor(2,3)`, because `3` isn't a type. If you want both 2 and 3 to be considered data, then they probably need to be in a list together. (Or a list of lists? Something like that)

Comment: But, did you look at the other stackover flow question link i mentioned

Comment: Yeah. I'm still looking in the documentation for a description of Tensor's constructor. Apparently it's an alias of FloatTensor, but I can't find documentation for that either. I haven't discounted the possibility that the other guy was transcribing his code from memory and got some details wrong.

Comment: @Kevin, yes.It was mentioned that it was an alias to FloatTensor. Also, according to documentation, torch.tensor can only create a tensor from a sequence. But, this other SO post puzzled me.

Comment: One more weird thing was i was actually able to create a tensor with torch.Tensor, but not with torch.tensor.

Comment: `torch.tensor([2,3])` or `torch.tensor((2,3))`  works for me

Comment: @UmangGupta, i just mentioned that. i know that a tensor can be created from a sequence. If you look at the other SO post i mentioned, he was able to create using torch.tensor(2,3). please note that, its not [2,3], its just two arguments with 2 and 3

Comment: If you want to create 2x3 tensor `torch.Tensor(2,3)` works for me.

Comment: _"he was able to create using torch.tensor(2,3)"_. Hmm, I don't see that anywhere. I see `torch.Tensor(2,3)`, but the capitalization is different.

Comment: @Kevin, i tried with torch.Tensor(2,3) too. i mentioned that in the question too.

Comment: @InAFlash Capital t works for me as expected.

Comment: I know, but it's important to keep the details straight or we'll end up going in circles. The other guy successfully did `torch.Tensor(2,3)`, but he never tried `torch.tensor(2,3)`. So we can't use the other question to inform our expectations about whether `torch.tensor(2,3)` should work.

Comment: @kevin, i even got an error with torch.Tensor(2,3). i mentioned about the error in the OP. Please look at the second error in the post

Comment: @InAFlash The point is I dont get that error (using torch v0.4

Comment: @UmangGupta, i am using the same version.

Comment: Can you try again with much clearer knowledge of `torch.tensor` and `torch.Tensor`

Comment: @UmangGupta, i have edited the post with screenshot

Comment: Ok! This looks like a bug in pytorch on windows. Seems like error is in print not in `torch.Tensor`. Worth posting to pytorch discussion forum https://discuss.pytorch.org/

Comment: @UmangGupta, yeah i think its an error with print statement. Look at the comment on the answer by Kevin

Comment: Are you running your script straight from an ordinary command prompt? Some IDEs have extra-fancy object introspection powers that can sometimes inadvertently break fragile objects that don't expect to get prodded. Try running `torch.Tensor(2,3)` a different environment.

Answer (score 0):

`torch.tensor()` expects a sequence or array_like to create a tensor whereas `torch.Tensor()` class can create a tensor with just shape information.

Here's the signature of `torch.tensor()`:

> **Docstring**:
>     tensor(data, dtype=None, device=None, requires_grad=False) -> Tensor
>
> Constructs a tensor with :attr:`data`.
>
> **Args**:
>      data (array_like): Initial data for the tensor. Can be a list, tuple,
>          NumPy `ndarray`, scalar, and other types.
>
> dtype (:class:`torch.dtype`, optional): the desired data type of returned tensor.

---

Regarding the `RuntimeError`: I cannot reproduce the error in Linux distros. Printing the tensor works perfectly fine from ipython terminal.

[image: ipython print tensor]

---

Taking a closer look at the error, this seems to be a problem only in Windows OS. As mentioned in the comments, have a look at the [issues/6339: Error when printing tensors containing large values](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/6339)

Comment: Ok, that explains why `torch.tensor(2,3)` didn't work. But why does `torch.Tensor(2,3)` cause a RuntimeError?

Comment: @Kevin, exactly. that was one of my question too

Comment: @kmario23, i just closed and tried it again. getting the same error

Comment: @kmario23, here is a weird thing i noticed.  So, i printed torch.Tensor(2,3) with a print statement and i started to get this error

Comment: but, if i try to just do torch.Tensor(2,3) in the console without a print statement, its working

Comment: This could be caused by too big values in the initialized memory `torch.Tensor()` uses.
See this for more information: https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/6339

Comment: ok, looks like it could be only reproduced with opening a command prompt and then running ipython and doing what i said. It was working when i directly opened a ipython shell

Comment: @M.Deckers, i think that's the problem. Thanks

Comment: @kmario23, were you able to reproduce the error with command prompt?

Comment: No, it works perfectly fine even with running it as a script instead of in ipython

Comment: @kmario23, can you loop 100 times and try printing torch.Tensor(2,2). and check if its giving run time error. Because, i did so, and i was getting run time error every now and then

Comment: @kmario23, so, i was reading about it and it's a bug. so, when its initialized, the value might be so, large sometimes that overflow happens and this is causing error

Comment: https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/6339 mentioned about the error. they said, they fixed it, but...even now, i got the error. can you tell me if you are able to reproduce the error when looped it 100 times